# Can a pointer be decleared as void storing chars?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char* pointer = new char [5];
strcpy_s(pointer,4, "foo");
```

I am not fully understanding how pointers work. In my understanding the variable pointer is supposed to store the starting address of the new allocated string of chars. If so why is it important that the pointer is a char since its only storing an address.

why can't i just type

```
void* pointer = new char [5]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because `strcpy_s` expects a `char*` as first parameter

Comment: Also what benefit would you gain from throwing away the type information by using a `void*`?

Comment: Void is a wildcard, it isn't good for using at start. You loose information about type.

Comment: The type here tells you what type the pointer is pointing to. Consider your example, and say you have `void *ptr;` ... Is it pointing to an `int`? A `double`? It could be anything, and, it could change over time too.

Comment: Reason 1): For type safety (C/C++ is a type-safe language after all). Reason 2): To know the size of individual elements. A `char` usually occupies 1 byte, whereas an double usually occupies 8. If you want to advance your pointer by 1 element, you have to add 1 byte in the first case and 8 in the second case. Pointer arithmetic does this for you already, but needs the type.

Comment: To fully use pointers you need to know 3 things: pointer to the data, size of the data, and the type of the data to correctly "move" pointer to the next value while reading.
- pointer to the data tells you only when the data starts in the memory
- data size tells you how many items have you allocated in current pointer
- and the type of pointer tells you what type of data is stored there. It its very important if you want to use for example `pointer[2]`, because depending on the type of variable it will calculate how many bytes we need to move from the start of pointer in memory

Comment: Btw, to store/work with pointers in a numerical way, i.e. as int, `void*` is not the appropriate type. For this purpose there is `std::uintptr_t`.

Comment: So yes after it has been compiled the pointer is just an address in memory. During compilation the compiler keeps track of its type to do all of the kind of things described in the other comments. And also helps in function signature checking, in the sense that you can only pass a char* to a function accepting a char* and not to a function accepting an int*. This is the typesafety part.

Comment: You tagged this question "C++". The correct answer for C++ would use neither arrays, pointers, `strcpy_s()`, nor `new`. Indeed, except for you using `new char[5]`, your question is about C, not C++. My recommendation: Find a better introduction to C++ than the one you are currently using. One that doesn't torture you with C constructs first, because virtually none of them are good, or necessary, in C++.

Comment: "why can't i just type" did you actually try it? The problem is not `void* pointer = new char [5];` but anything after that, because there isnt much yuo can do with a `void*`

Comment: I did try it and it did not work but i wanted a better explanation. Thank you all i now understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pointer needs to know the size of its element, thanks to it you can use `[] operator` to reach a certain element of the array, how else would it know how much memory it has to move to get to the n-th element? If you could declare a pointer to any type as void, then it would have to automatically deduce the type it points to. Consider this piece of code:

```
char* pointer = new char[5];
pointer[3] = 'a';
```

for `void*` this would not be possible. I suppose that the strcpy_s function expects the first parameter as `char*`, not `void*` and that is the reason why your code doesn't compile. Pointer itself just allows you to know where some variable/array or even function is in memory, but when you specify pointer's type it gives it more flexibility.

Comment: Does the pointer not know this information already when you write new **char** [5].

Comment: @Mephobia You throw away this information when you convert `char*` to `void*`.

Comment: the pointer itself is just a position of the start in memory

Comment: @Mephobia • *Does the pointer not know this information already...?*  When the pointer is `char* pointer = new char[5];` it knows the information.  When the pointer is `auto pointer = new char[5];` is knows the information.  When the pointer is `void* pointer = new char[5];` the information has been intentionally discarded.